# SD of a Binomial distribution - multiply or divide by n

Tags: binomial-distribution

I had this problem to solve:

> If an insurance company has 10,000 policies, and each has 0.1
> probability of making a claim, what is the standard deviation of the
> fraction of policies which result in a claim?

The suggested solution was:

> The standard deviation is √(p(1-p)/n)     = √(0.1(1-0.1)/10000)     =
> √(0.09/10000)     = 0.3/100     = 0.003

Can someone explain to me why in this binomial distribution, the above solution divides by n. My understanding is that the standard deviation of a binomial distribution should be: :

> √(np(1-p))

Comment: Is it asking for the *number* of policies that result in a claim or the *fraction* of policies that result in a claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's just start from first principles.  Let $X$ be a random variable which takes on value 1 with probability $p$.  If each policy is IID and we have $n$ policies, then

$$ \operatorname{Var} \left( \sum_{k=1} ^ n X\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n \operatorname{Var}(X) = np(1-p) $$

and so the standard deviation is $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$.

The quantity $\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$ is the standard error in estimating the probability of success for the underlying bernoulli processes.

$$ \operatorname{Var} \left( \bar{X} \right) = \operatorname{Var} \left( \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X  \right) = \dfrac{1}{n^2} n p (1-p) = \dfrac{p(1-p)}{n} \>.$$

Comment: Your second expression is also the "standard deviation of the fraction of policies which result in a claim" asked for in the quoted question

Comment: When the variance of policies is available, why do we still need to compute the variance of the mean?

Comment: @HaydarAl-Rikabi The sample mean is itself a random variable. We need to estimate it’s variability so that we, for example, construct confidence intervals to determine what values of the mean are consistent with the observed data.